# Hay alguna manera de hacer esto de una manera más practica?

Tags: c++

soy una persona autodidacta así que perdón si mi pregunta es tonta, pero me encontré un problema que era hacer un programa en c++ en el que ingreses un numero del uno al cien y que te regresara el nombre de ese número y pensé bueno esta fácil lo haces con ifs, pero cuando lo estaba escribiendo me di cuenta de que era muy largo y creo que en la practica no serviría de nada, miren esto es lo que trataba de hacer, alguna idea de como lo pueda hacer más practico?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()  
{
    int a;
    cin>> a;
    if (a==1){
        cout<<"uno";
    }
    if (a==2){
        cout<<"dos";
    }
    if (a==3){
        cout<<"tres";
    }if (a==4){
        cout<<"cuatro";
    }
    if (a==5){
        cout<<"cinco";
    }
    if (a==6){
        cout<<"seis";
    } if (a==7){
        cout<<"siete";
    }
    if (a==8){
        cout<<"ocho";
    }
    if (a==9){
        cout<<"nueve";
    }
    if (a==10){
        cout<<"diez";
    }
    if (a==11){
        cout<<"once";
    }
    if (a==12){
        cout<<"doce";
    }
    if (a==13){
        cout<<"trece";
    }
    if (a==14){
        cout<<"catorce";
    }
    if (a==15){
        cout<<"quince";
    }
    if (a==16){
        cout<<"dieciseis";
    }
    if (a==17){
        cout<<"diecisiete";
    }
    if (a==18){
        cout<<"dieciocho";
    }
    if (a==19){
        cout<<"diecinueve";
    }
    if (a==20){
        cout<<"veinte";
    }
}
```

Comment: Del 1 al 100? Es mucho para tantos if. Puedes usar un array de estructuras con un campo número y otro nombre. Entonces con un switch evalúas un numero ingresado y lo buscas en el array. Si lo encuentra qué muestre su campo nombre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La mayoría de los números se escriben según un patron:

```
20 -> veinte
21 -> veintiuno
22 -> veintidos
23 -> veintitres
```

Por lo tanto, una solución es tener almacenados los especiales, aquellos que incumplen la regla, y usar una formula genérica para el resto:

```
void enletra( int num ) {
  const char *nombres[10][10] = {
    { "cero", "uno", "dos", ... },
    { "diez", "unce", "doce", "trece", ... },
    { "veinte", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, ... },
    { "treinta", ... },
    ...
  };

  const char *prefijo[] = { nullptr, nullptr, "veinti", "treinta y ", ... }

  if( num < 10 ) {
    // Caso simple.
    std::cout << nombres[0][num];
    return;
  }

  int decenas = num / 10;
  int unidades = num % decenas;

  if( nombres[decenas][unidades] != nullptr ) {
    // Caso especial; nombre que incumple la regla.
    std::cout << nombres[decenas][unidades];
  } else {
    // El nombre cumple la regla.
    std::cout << prefijo[decenas] << nombres[0][unidades];
  }
}
```