# Dar un numero del uno al cien y regresar el nombre de dicho número

Tags: c++

perdón si mi pregunta es tonta pero estoy aprendiendo solo, estoy haciendo un código que al ingresar un número del 1 al 100 te regrese el nombre, el código esta casi completo pero no se como agregar el 11, el 12, el 13, el 14 y el 15 sin afectar a los demás números, también hay una "y" que quiero que solo aparezca en números como 31 así treinta "y" uno pero cuando hago esto también lo agrega a números como el uno y queda como "y" uno, aquí esta mi codigo, y de antemano gracias

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
    {
        int a, b;
        cin>>a;
        cin>> b;
        if (a==9){
            cout<<"noventa";
        }
        if (a==8){
            cout<<"ochenta";
        }
        if (a==7){
            cout<<"setenta";
        }
        if (a==6){
            cout<<"sesenta";
        }
        if (a==5){
            cout<<"cincuenta";
        }
        if (a==4){
            cout<<"cuarenta";
        }
        if (a==3){
            cout<<"treinta";
        }
        if (a==1, b==0){
            cout<<"diez";
        }
        else if (a==1){
            cout<<"dieci";
        }
        if (a==2){
            cout<<"veinti";
        }
        if (a!=2, b!=0, a!=0, a!=1) {
            cout<<" y ";
        }
        if (b==1){
            cout<<"uno";
        }
        if (b==2){
            cout<<"dos";
        }
        if (b==3){
            cout<<"tres";
        }
        if (b==4){
            cout<<"cuatro";
        }
        if (b==5){
            cout<<"cinco";
        }
        if (b==6){
            cout<<"seis";
        }
        if (b==7){
            cout<<"siete";
        }
        if (b==8){
            cout<<"ocho";
        }
        if (b==9){
            cout<<"nueve";
        }
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Hay alguna manera de hacer esto de una manera más practica?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/419561/hay-alguna-manera-de-hacer-esto-de-una-manera-m%c3%a1s-practica)

Comment: Lamentablemente apenas estoy iniciando y me resulto difícil entender completamente la respuesta, pero me resulto útil la idea que me dió de separar los números como 30 y 31 que ambos incluyen la palabra treinta y asi, no es que no quiera hacerlo de una manera más fácil, es que todavía desconozco demasiado

Comment: No puse mas números porque, sin ofender, algo tan trivial no merecía mas esfuerzo por mi parte; la idea era que tú rellenaras los elementos restantes de los vectores. Pero tengo la sospecha de que no te manejas con punteros ni arrays. **DEBES APRENDER PUNTEROS**. C++ sin punteros es como un coche sin batería: ocupa espacio, y te puedes meter dentro para no mojarte, pero no te va a llevar a ningún sitio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (a!=2, b!=0, a!=0, a!=1) {
   cout<<" y ";
}
```

Esto no combina lógicamente las distintas expresiones.

`a!=2, b!=0, ...` es una secuencia de expresiones, y el `if` toma como resultado una de ellas (no tengo muy claro si la primera o la última).

Si quieres combinar lógicamente las expresiones, tienes que usar los **operadores booleanos**:

- && -> AND. Verdadero solo si los dos operandos son verdaderos.
- || -> OR. Falso solo si los dos operandos son falsos.
- ! -> Negación. Convierte falso en positivo y viceversa.

Por ejemplo (no digo que sea lo que buscas porque no tengo muy clara tu lógica):

```
if ((a != 2) && (a != 1) && (a != 0)) || (b != 0)) {
   cout << " y ";
}
```

Como comentario final, intenta centrar tus preguntas **en el problema**. Está bien explicar el objetivo general del programa como un poco de introducción, pero la "chicha" de la pregunta debería ser el problema específico (en este caso, que te aparece un "y" que no esperas).

Y en vez de dejar todo el código, intenta encontrar la parte relevante (en este caso, donde escribes el "y") para dejar más claro qué es lo que buscas.

Eso hará que la pregunta parezca más "estaba haciendo un programa y hay algo que no sé hacer" y menos "quiero que alguien escriba el programa por mí."

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias por las ideas, aquí esta mi resultado final, se que no es practico y es muy largo pero espero que le sirva a alguien

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
    {
        int a, b;
        cin>>a;
        cin>> b;
        if ((a ==1) && (b == 0)) {
            cout << "diez";
        }
        if (a==9){
            cout<<"noventa";
        }
        if (a==8){
            cout<<"ochenta";
        }
        if (a==7){
            cout<<"setenta";
        }
        if (a==6){
            cout<<"sesenta";
        }
        if (a==5){
            cout<<"cincuenta";
        }
        if (a==4){
            cout<<"cuarenta";
        }
        if (a==3){
            cout<<"treinta";
        }
        else if ((a==1)&&(b!=0)&&(b!=1)&&(b!=2)&&(b!=3)&&(b!=4)&&(b!=5)){
            cout<<"dieci";
        }
        if ((a ==2) && (b == 0)) {
            cout << "veinte";
        }
        else if (a==2){
            cout<<"veinti";
        }
        if ((a != 2) && (a != 1) && (a != 0) && (b != 0)) {
            cout << " y ";
        }
        if ((b==1)&&(a!=1)){
            cout<<"uno";
        }
        if ((b==2)&&(a!=1)){
            cout<<"dos";
        }
        if ((b==3)&&(a!=1)){
            cout<<"tres";
        }
        if ((b==4)&&(a!=1)){
            cout<<"cuatro";
        }
        if ((b==5)&&(a!=1)){
            cout<<"cinco";
        }
        if ((b==6)&&(b!=1)){
            cout<<"seis";
        }
        if ((b==7)&&(b!=1)){
            cout<<"siete";
        }
        if ((b==8)&&(b!=1)){
            cout<<"ocho";
        }
        if ((b==9)&&(b!=1)){
            cout<<"nueve";
        }
        if ((a ==1) && (b == 1)) {
            cout << "once";
        }
        if ((a ==1) && (b == 2)) {
            cout << "doce";
        }
        if ((a ==1) && (b == 3)) {
            cout << "trece";
        }
        if ((a ==1) && (b == 4)) {
            cout << "catorce";
        }
        if ((a ==1) && (b == 5)) {
            cout << "quince";
        }
}
```